# Using SSD as boot drive and HDD as storage boot issues

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd, windows-10

Currently I have two installations of Windows 10 on my computer, one on my HDD that came with my laptop and another on an SSD to which I installed recently. My EFI System Partition and Recovery partition is on my HDD, but I wish to use this solely as a storage drive. My SSD shows up with no partitions other than my OS installation. How would I safely transfer all of my Windows Boot Loader settings/options to my SSD and use my HDD as storage? Currently when I start up my computer it gives me the option of starting Windows on volume 2 (SSD) or volume 6 (HDD).

Comment: Why didn't you format the HDD while installing OS in SSD ?

Comment: I unfortunately didn't have an extra storage drive large enough so I kept my stuff on the HDD so that I can migrate to it after installing Windows on my SSD

Comment: You could possibly do this with the bootrec command-line tool. You may be able to remove your bcd file from C:\Boot and rebuild a new one which only points to the OS on your SSD.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a partition program (google that) and then use the copy option within those programs to make a clone. There are several which are recommended by experienced users on this site.
* DriveImageXML
* Marcrium Reflect
* Partition Wizard
These worked for me, but it may be different for other. **Your mileage may vary**

Then boot the computer, putting the SSD at the exact same place where the HDD was.